# Why my VBA code creates line plot instead of scatter plot?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to generate scatter plot from 2 data-columns, but instead I get a line plot where data of the first column is ignored (i.e.: if I have 1000 points, on x-axis I see values from 1 to 1000, regardless of the data stored in 1st column). I can't find the error in my code. What's wrong?

```
Public Sub Graph_Refresh()

    Dim cht As Chart
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim seriesIndex As Integer
    Set cht = Sheets("Graph").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
    seriesIndex = 0

    ' ***** CLEAR OLD CONTENT *****
    cht.ChartArea.ClearContents

    ' ***** NON CHANGEABLE PARAMETERS *****
    'Format Font Type and Size
    cht.ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers                                   ' scatter plot
    cht.ChartArea.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial"
    cht.ChartArea.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 12
    cht.HasTitle = False      ' No chart title
    'cht.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueGridLinesMajor)   'Gridlines

    'Adjust x-axis
    cht.HasAxis(xlCategory, xlPrimary) = True
    cht.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    cht.Axes(xlCategory).AxisTitle.Text = "Frequency [MHz]"
    cht.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = Sheets("Graph").Range("AI7").Value
    cht.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = Sheets("Graph").Range("AI8").Value

    'Adjust y-axis
    cht.HasAxis(xlValue, xlPrimary) = True
    cht.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    cht.Axes(xlValue).AxisTitle.Text = "S-Parameters [dB]"
    cht.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Sheets("Graph").Range("AI9").Value
    cht.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Sheets("Graph").Range("AI10").Value
    cht.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = -100

    ' Data Series
    For i = 1 To 5
                    seriesIndex = seriesIndex + 1
                    cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                    With Sheets("Graph")
                        cht.SeriesCollection(seriesIndex).Name = .Cells(6 + (i - 1) * 4).Value & " S11"
                    End With
                    cht.SeriesCollection(seriesIndex).XValues = "='" & Sheets("Data" & CStr(i)).Name & "'!$K$4:$K$10004"
                    cht.SeriesCollection(seriesIndex).Values = "='" & Sheets("Data" & CStr(i)).Name & "'!$L$4:$L$10004"
                    ' Set line size and color
                    With cht.SeriesCollection(seriesIndex)
                        .Format.Line.Weight = 2.25
                        .Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
                        .Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
                        .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255,0,0)
                        .MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleNone
                    End With

    Next i


    ' Legend


End Sub
```

Data are stored in sheets "Data1" - "Data5", and the range should be ok. Chart "Chart 1" already exists (that's why I don't create it).

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Well you specify `xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers` (LINES) and expect to see no lines?  Try `xlXYScatter` instead.  Also `.Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue` - why if you don't want the lines?  Remove the entire `With cht.SeriesCollection(seriesIndex)` block and it works fine

Comment: Sorry, my question was not clear. I edited the text to clarify it.
My point is that I want to plot [column 2 values] vs [column 1 values], while I get a plot with only [column 2 values] on y-axis, and values from 1 to Nsamples on x-axis.

Answer (score 0):

After some more investigation, I fund the answer. I leave it here for anyone who might be interested.

The problem was due to the fact that the data range that I provided included empty cells (or, to be more precise, cells with functions returning blanks). 
Resizing XValues and Values to include only cells with data solved the problem.